# Adding boot argument

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot

I am trying to understand, how boot arguments are created and passed to the Kernel.

I am thinking the following steps, please confirm.

1.Add the new boot argument in the header file under U-Boot source(include/configs/)

> My understanding is, each board is having one header file under
>   "include/configs" of U-boot source. Please correct me if I am wrong.

2.Modify the Kernel to accept the new boot argument.

> Doubht) Please tell me where to modify the Kernel to accept the new
>   boot argument.

Could you please guide me to understand one existing boot arg implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct for 1.

I don't know about the kernel modification. Probably in the function receiving the arguments (I think they are stacked like in a main() function).